# jQuery anchor based breadcrumbs?

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, breadcrumbs

So, I have a website with a accordion menu that uses anchor tags in order to navigate the site.
 
There are no other pages but one page with all the content in it seperated by anchors.
 I'm looking for a breadcrumb that gets displayed when either scrolling to a specific anchored tag (nested) or clicking on a anchored link in the accordion menu (nested).
 How would I create something like this in jQuery?
 I was thinking about adding something like classes to the a name tags to generate the breadcrumb in jquery using a isvisible in viewport script.
 However when I think about it, what happens when a user copy and pastes a url with an anchor in it and it starts at that page,
 then it doesn't scroll past the other anchors and the breadcrumb won't display properly.
 How should I go about creating this?
Does this mean I'd have to create the hierarchy somehow in javascript/jQuery?

The following jsfiddle shows an idea on how it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/6dnxcoet/3/

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#information">Information</a>
    <ul>
      <lI><a href="#contact">Contact</a></lI>
      <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav id="breadcrumb">
  <ul class="breadcrumb clear-initial-trail">
  <li><div><a href="#home">Home</a></div></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="page">
    <h1><a name="home">Home</a></h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <h2><a name="information">Information</a></h2>
  <div class="page">
    <h3><a name="contact">Contact</a></h3>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h3><a name="about-us">About Us</a></h3>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h3><a name="news">News</a></h3>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</main>

.page {
  height: 800px;
  background-color:red;
  width:400px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

main {
  text-align:center;
}

#menu {
  position:fixed;
}

#breadcrumb {
  position:fixed;
  right:200px;
  top:0px;
}

.breadcrumb{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.breadcrumb.clear-initial-trail > li:first-child > div {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

.breadcrumb.clear-initial-trail > li:first-child > div::before {
    display: none;
}

.breadcrumb > li > div{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #999;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.breadcrumb > li > div::after{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 100%;
    content: '';
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 15px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-left-color: #999;
}

.breadcrumb > li > div::before{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 100%;
    content: '';
    background-color: #999;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 15px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
```

I want the breadcrumb to update when it scrolls to an anchored tag and when the links are clicked in the nav. Home should always be there, information should be second and the other ones third.

Comment: I can imagine what you are asking, but that's all in my head and it would be my implementation. What you are lacking here is being more detailed (with code) on how you want it to be done. First of all you need to provide a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. To answer your other question, yes this is very doable with JS/JQuery + CSS + HTML

Comment: I'll try to create a jsfiddle and some code to display what I'm trying to do. This'll take some time, I'll update my post as soon as possible.

Comment: don't rush, the community will keep an eye out for your question. In practice I find that in trying to re-create my problem, I end up finding the solution for it

Comment: I made the css and html to give an idea on what I'm trying to do. I haven't written my own javascript or jquery yet because I don't exactly know how I should go about creating it.

Comment: I am pretty sure I did a jsFiddle that does what you are thinking about, or at least resembles your idea (looking around for it)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help so far, I really appreciate it. In the meanwhile I'm trying to create something myself by trial and error. Hopefully I can get something working soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have tried to get it to work and it seems okay so far, altho I would like to add some animation to it. I guess I should add a hide class to it and then .show().animate()? Anyways here is the code with the jsfiddle:

```
(function($) {

/**
    * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
    * Licensed under the MIT license.
    * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
    *
    * @author Sam Sehnert
    * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
    *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
    *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
*/

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t            = $(this),
        $w            = $(window),
        viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top          = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

  return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

function updatecrumb(parent, page) {
  var breadcrumb = $('.breadcrumb');
  var current = '';
  var active = '';
  if (parent) {
    if (parent == 'empty') {
      if (breadcrumb.find('.currentpage').length) {
          breadcrumb.find('.currentpage').replaceWith('');
      }
    }
    else {
      current += "<li class=\"currentpage\"><div><a href=\"#" + parent.children(':first-child')[0].name + "\"> " + parent.children(':first-child').children().text() + "</a></div></li>";
      if (breadcrumb.find('.currentpage').length)
      {
        breadcrumb.find('.currentpage').replaceWith(current);
      }
      else {
        breadcrumb.append(current);    
      }
    }
  }
  if (page) {
    if (page == 'empty') {
        if (breadcrumb.find('.active').length) {
          breadcrumb.find('.active').replaceWith('');
        }
    }
    else {
      if (page.attr('id') != "home") {
        active += "<li class=\"active\"><div><a href=\"#" + page.children(':first-child')[0].name + "\"> " + page.children(':first-child').children().text() + "</a></div></li>";
        if (breadcrumb.find('.active').length)
        {
          breadcrumb.find('.active').replaceWith(active);
        }
        else {
          breadcrumb.append(active);
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var page,
        parent,
        parentcount = 0,
        pagecount = 0;
    $('.parent-page').each(function() {
      if ($(this).visible(true)) {
        parent = $(this);
        parentcount += 1;
        updatecrumb(parent);
      }
    });
    $('.page').each(function() {
      if ($(this).visible(true)) {
        page = $(this);
        if (page.attr('id') != "home") {
          pagecount +=1;
        }
        updatecrumb(null, page);
      }
    })
    if (parentcount == 0) {
      updatecrumb('empty');
    }
    if (pagecount == 0) {
      updatecrumb(null, 'empty');
    }
});
```

The jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6dnxcoet/4/
And ofcourse there is room for improvement so if anyone has an idea on how to optimize, improve the code. Please... Don't hold back.